# Liquid jet in the absence of gravity

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics

On earth, we have liquid jets which are falling and accelerating under influence of gravity ( this cause their radius to decrease )

My question is about liquids in the absence of gravity. Can we make liquid jets where there's no gravitational force?

Comment: What do you mean "Can we make liquid jets where there's no gravitational force?" Of course we can -- we take some liquid to space and make it shoot out through a hole. That's a liquid jet without gravity. Is there something more specific you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Mohi, if confusion arises from question why fluid in no-gravity conditions would stick together, it's because of electromagnetic force between molecules in fluid.